# User Account Control Manager plus having no password for the administrator

Tags: windows-10, uac

I could not opt for startup settings, to start in safe mode my hp machine.
Why! because I also don't have administrator privileges.
I downloaded a CVE-2017-012_x64.exe file, installing it was a problem because windows firewall was enabled.
Disabling windows service wasn't possible. Writing the registry wasn't allowed.
This is really depressing me, on installing my programs or running my command prompt as an admin. Am even thinking of re-installing windows.
I tried lots of fixes like the ones above but this couldn't help me out.
This is because enabling my User Account Control Manager has become a problem.

Comment: "I also don't have administrator privileges" you mean someone else is admin, or you lost control of admin?

Comment: If you don't have Administrator permissions you should have somebody who does have Administrator permissions determine if this executable you want to install actually should be installed.  The file name does not appear to be legitimate to, CVE vulnerabilities, are not resolve with files like that on Windows.

Comment: Look, it's only one account in my pc which runs a dual boot windows and Linux., Maybe I admit administrator privileges I  have but not the password. For it, I lost it

Comment: So, this is just an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Your real problem is that you have lost the admin password… so why not ask about that instead?

Comment: ..it's indeed an XY Problem Indeed you get me well sir. But it's like, I tampered with the cmd somewhere thinking it won't work out and changed my rights from admin to standard but still I put a not-to-mind password which I later forgot, but that way, atleast the "yes" box when installing a program should prompt me to put my wrong one